# Codeigniter routes and Language Identifier

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have URI Language Identifier on my website I did it according to directions on codeigniter WIKI. It works fine. But How Can I get name of controller because $this->uri->segment(2) == id and $this->uri->segment(1) == name of the metod?

This is my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "page";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->uri->segment(1)
```

refers the ist parameter after your base_url()

**For example**

```
base url = 'http://localhost/site/'
```

**URL**    `http://localhost/site/controller/method`

```
$this->uri->segment(1) = 'controller'
$this->uri->segment(2) = 'method'
```

Now check the below case also

```
base url = 'http://testsite/test/site/'
```

**URL**   `http://testsite/test/site/controller/method`

```
$this->uri->segment(1) = 'controller'
$this->uri->segment(2) = 'method'
```

Comment: Yes I understand it, but I installed URI Language Identifier and after that is set segment(1) = 'metod' and segment(1) = 'id' I dont know why. I need to get name of controller.

Comment: @PatrikvanDendis: What is the position of 'method' and 'id' after base_url() ?

Comment: http://localhost/privat/controller/method/id - This is my URL. And base_url() is http://localhost/privat/

Comment: Any thing mentioned in your ".htaccess" like "RewriteBase /<link>/" ?

Comment: @PatrikvanDendis: once try my code
<code>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|indexcp\.php?|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/-]+)$ index.php?/welcome/$1 

RewriteRule ^(CSI) index.php?/CSI
AddType text/x-component .htc


</code>

Comment: No. It report me errors and when I repaired this errors my main problem wasnt repaired.